# How do I Activate the Signatures Workflow?

Tags: site-template, feature-activation, solution-package

After fixing the intranet site that was deleted, I am re-establishing some pages that were lost. I have a site template that I created and when I try to use it on the top level site, I receive the following error message {} and I found what this message meant by going to this [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/mcsnoiwb/features-and-their-guids-in-sp2010). I went to Site Actions --> Site Settings --> Site Collection Administration --> Site Collection Features, but do not see 'SignaturesWorkflow' to activate it.

Also, if I activate the template in the top level Galleries --> Solutions, is it necessary for me to also activate it in the subsites of the top level site as well? Or if I only need it for the subsites, should I ONLY activate the template in the solutions gallary for that specific subsite?

Here is a screen shot of the error message.

[image: Error Message for Site Collection Feature, SignaturesWorkflow]

The error message I am receiving is:

> The site template requires that the Feature
> {6c09612b-46af-4b2f-8dfc-59185c962a29} be activated in the site
> collection.

I have a link that I go to to find out what the GUIDs are and this specific GUID is for 'SignaturesWorkflow' the link for this site is in the message above. Where do I go to activate the SignaturesWorkflow?

I have already gone to Site Collection Features @ the top-level-site, but it does not appear in here. So where can I find it to activate it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so I was searching on how to fix this error and came accross the following [link](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/use-a-collect-signatures-workflow-HA010154428.aspx). I hope this helps those of you who may be experiencing the same thing I am. Now I activated the 2007 workflow in the site collection and have another GUID error message. I went to the site that I mentioned in the first post and it does not contain the information for the GUID.

'The site template requires that the Feature {e8389ec7-70fd-4179-a1c4-6fcb4342d7a0} be activated in the site collection'.

We can close this one and I guess, if I can't find the resolution, I will have to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in SharePoint Powershell:

```
Enable-SPFeature "6c09612b-46af-4b2f-8dfc-59185c962a29" -URL "http(s)://YourStieCollectionURL"
```

(because feature scope is "site")

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to Site Actions -> Site Settings -> Site collection features (under ‘Site Collection Administration’ section).
2. Activate Publishing Approval Workflow, Workflows and SharePoint 2007 Workflows in sequence.
3. Now when you go to list or library tab -> workflow settings -> Add a workflow, by default, Disposition Approval Workflow and Three-state workflow will be available. When above 2 steps are performed Collect Signature and Collect Feedback workflows will be available.